# Background Image of Grid doesn't work

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I set a background image to my Gird, and it displays correct in the designer, but when I run the app, the image doesn't appear, the background is black, anyone has any ideas? Below is my code.

```
<Page.Resources>        
    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundImage" ImageSource="People/Images/Background.jpg"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{StaticResource BackgroundImage}">
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried absolute path /People/Images/Background.jpg or ms-appx:///People/Images/Background.jpg

Comment: Yes, I've tried, it displays in the designer correct, but when I run the project, it couldn't display

Comment: this doesn't help, but works fine on my machine... used your exact markup in a new Blank App template and created a folder hierarchy as you have here

Comment: It is really confusing! If the path isn't correct, the image will also not displayed in the designer, but it displays correct, only disappear when run the project

Comment: is there more to the app than what's in a Blank App template in Visual Studio?  Is something at runtime collapsing the grid so it has no height or width?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As Jim suggests, you need to have the correct absolute path.

I originally had:

> Assets\Quizzes\image.png

It displayed fine in the designer but not at runtime. I switched it to:

> ms-appx:///Assets/Quizzes/image.png

Now it displays correctly in the designer and runtime.